# Print "none" when value not found and move on

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

This is my code for a TripAdvisor scraper:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import os

theurl = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotels-g293810-Malawi-Hotels.html"
thepage = urllib
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)

soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
data_all = soup.findAll('div', {"class":"listing_info popIndexValidation"})
link = soup.findAll('div', attrs={"class":"listing_title"})

init_data = open('/Users/paribaker/Desktop/scrapping/TripAdvisor/Inv/initdata.txt', 'a')
init_info = []

try:
    for data_all in soup.findAll('div', {"class":"listing_info popIndexValidation"}):
        init_info.append(data_all.find('a', {'class':'property_title'}).text +",\t")
        init_info.append(data_all.find('span', {'class':"more"}).text +",\t")
        init_info.append(data_all.find('div', {'class':"clickable_tags"}).text +",\t")
        init_info.append([img["alt"] for img in data_all.select("img[alt]")])
        init_info.append("\n")

except  AttributeError:
    init_info.append("non")

init_data.write("".join(map(lambda x: str(x), init_info)))
init_data.close

init_data.write("".join(map(lambda x: str(x), init_info)))
init_data.close
```

This fulfills all the functions that I need for now, I am having one small issue that I can't seem to work around.

I used a try-except block to iterate over any errors. I thought this would just ignore an error print none and move on to the next item on the list. 
Instead, once it reaches an item without a value it cuts the code and breaks out.

The code iterates through the list of items I want appended into a list, in this particular page the hotels I'm scraping the last two have no reviews no stars or anything of the sort, so once it reaches to the second last hotel it gets and appends the name, but then appends none and breaks. 
How can I tell the program to print none when no value is found and carry on iterating?

Answer (score 1):

When an exception is caught, code execution skips to the `except` block, and then continues from there. Instead of:

```
try:
    for ...:
        init_info.append(...)
except AttributeError: 
    init_info.append("none")
```

try this:

```
for ...:
    try ...:
        init_info.append(...)
    except AttributeError: 
        init_info.append("none")
```